# Performance of Picture Marker Vs Character Marker (font)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, symbology, performance, arcgis-silverlight-api

We have a point data type to symbolise.  The feature classes can often contain more than 6000 points up to 20000.  There are about 30 different symbol catergories to these points.

My question is what's more performant - creating EMF pictures and symbolising using picture markers or create a font and use character marker symbolisation?

We would be using this dataset in both ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server (silverlight API).

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that CharacterMarker symbols draw faster than PictureMarker Symbols, thats assuming your using just one layer in your CharacterMarker symbol.

This [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s600000014000000.htm) has some good information:

- The drawing performance of marker
  symbols, whether used to symbolize
  points or as a component of one of
  the other types of symbols, can be
  improved greatly by using simple
  marker symbols and single-layer
  character marker symbols; these are
  the best choices for symbolizing
  large point feature datasets.
- emf pictures will draw faster than .bmp pictures

If it were me, I would try both, and then use the 'preview' option from the [Map Service Publishing Toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sq00000018000000.htm), to get an idea on which one draws quicker.

In terms of consuming this in a Silverlight application, I would also consider looking at using a [clustering technique](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/samples/start.htm#SimpleClusterer) to render your points when at small scales.